# Inequalities on matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $K=(A+D)^{-1}A$ where $A$ is symmetric positive definite and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with positive elements. Is it true that $\|K\|\leq 1$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is the induced $2$-norm?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by the $2$-induced norm? The square root of the sum of squares of the entries of the matrix is one possible interpretation; the norm of the matrix as an operator between $l_2^n$ spaces is another; which one is it?

Comment: @uniquesolution it's a standard term for the second one.  That is, he means the "spectral norm".

Comment: $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the maximum singular value.

Comment: @uniquesolution "induced" here refers to the fact that the matrix norm is derived from the vector norm, i.e. we compute the norm of the operator between vector spaces.

Comment: @user293017 you were right about that; good catch

Answer (score 2):

If $AD=DA$, the inequality is true: you have, if $d_n$ is the least entry in the diagonal of $D$, 
$$
A+D\geq A+d_nI.
$$
So $(A+D)^{-1}\leq(A+d_nI)^{-1}$, and so
$$
(A+D)^{-1}A=A^{1/2}(A+D)^{-1}A^{1/2}\leq A^{1/2}(A+d_nI)^{-1}A^{1/2}=(A+d_nI)^{-1}A
$$
Now the inequality follows from the fact that inequalities between positive elements preserve norm, and $(A+d_nI)^{-1}A$ is positive and has eigenvalues $\lambda/(\lambda+d_n)$.

In general, the answer is no. For instance with 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 2&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix},\ \ D=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix},
$$
[we have](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(%7B%7B2,1%7D,%7B1,1%7D%7D%2B%7B%7B1,0%7D,%7B0,2%7D%7D)%5E(-1).%7B%7B2,1%7D,%7B1,1%7D%7D) 
$$
K=(A+D)^{-1}A=\frac13\,\begin{bmatrix}5&4\\7&4\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\|K\|\geq 7/3>1$.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Why $(A+D)^{-1}A=A^{1/2}(A+D)^{-1}A^{1/2}$?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/134190/22857).