# Do almost commuting matrices almost commute with the square root?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

If $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ self-adjoint matrices with $B$ positive semidefinite and $\|B\|_F\leq1$ such that $$\|AB-BA\|_F\leq \epsilon,$$ where $\|A\|^2_F:=tr(A^*A)$ is the Frobenius (or Hilbert-Schmidt) norm. I'd like to know if there is a constant $C>0$ such that $\|A\sqrt{B}-\sqrt{B}A\|_F<C\epsilon$ is independent of $n$.

Using the solution to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134186/does-certain-matrix-commutes-with-square-root-of-another-one) one can use the fact that there is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ such that $p(B)=\sqrt{B}$ and it follows that there is a constant $K>0$ such that for any polynomial $p(B)$ we see that $$\|Ap(B)-p(B)A\|_F\leq Kn\epsilon,$$ just using the submutliplicativity of $\|\cdot\|_F$ and the triangle inequality. However, in the case where $p(B)=\sqrt{B}$, I would like to know if there is a bound that depends on $\epsilon$ but not $n$.

**Edit:** in the comments of the linked question, the author of the answer has noted that the degree of the polynomial is at least the number of distinct eigenvalues of $B$, which makes sense if you are using the polynomial that interpolates the eigenvalues.

Comment: Are we given that $B$ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: @Ben yes! I will add that to the question.

Comment: I guess that $\| \cdot \|_F$ denotes the "Frobenius norm"? I would tend to call it the Hilbert-Schmidt norm or simply the entrywise $L^2$-norm. Anyway, whatever the norm is called, you should explain what norm you're referring to in the the post.

Comment: @Mike will do thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Pick a self-adjoint matrix $X$ and an orthogonal projection $Y\ne I$ such that $\|XY-YX\|_F=\epsilon>0$. Let $t>0,\ A=\frac1tX$ and $B=tY$. Since $Y$ is an orthogonal projection, we have $\sqrt{Y}=Y$ and $\sqrt{B}=\sqrt{t}\,Y$. Therefore $\|AB-BA\|_F=\epsilon$ but $\|A\sqrt{B}-\sqrt{B}A\|_F=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\epsilon$. When $t\to0$, we have $\|B\|_F\le1$ but $\|A\sqrt{B}-\sqrt{B}A\|_F\to\infty$.

Comment: @Zerox Aren't orthogonal projections precisely those which are self-adjoint?

Comment: @Rammus Although orthogonal projections are self-adjoint, where I made a mistake, not every self-adjoint operater is a pure orthogonal projection, such as $2 \cdot \operatorname{Id}$.

Comment: @Zerox Yes, I meant a projection is orthogonal iff it is self-adjoint.

Comment: I wonder if the statement holds with the additional assumption that $A$ is an orthogonal projection?

Comment: @Condo Wait. I forgot that you need $C$ to be independent of $n$. Now I am not sure...

Comment: @user1551 but when $t\rightarrow \infty$ wont $\|B\|$ have unbounded operator norm? I want $\|B\|_F\leq 1$.

Comment: @Condo I considered $t\to0$ in my answer. Not $t\to\infty$.

Comment: @user1551 yes, you are correct! my bad.